# PHP Upload File

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to upload file to server with php script. I'm Using `MAMP` with `PHP7.0.8`

I have HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="hi" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
    Send File: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

And simple php:

```
  <?php

$uploaddir = 'img/';
print_r($uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']));

  echo '<pre>';
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
  } else {
      echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
  }

  echo 'info:';
  print_r($_FILES);
  echo "<br />";
  print_r($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
  print "</pre>";

?>
```

My result is:

Possible file upload attack!

```
info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => high-school-icon.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpoaPmYv
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1807
        )

)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @Rostyslav Is it working now?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry, it was stupid mistake. Wrong way for `$uploaddir = 'img/';`

Comment: this is an excuse, but in no what is that a solution

Comment: @Nasral that's was actually a solution

Answer (score 1):

[Form action documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

**Error:**
`action="hi"`

**Change it to:** `action="simple.php"`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="simple.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
    Send File: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Comment: That's not a solution.. 
action="hi" actually send me to hi.php, where is running php script

Comment: Please share the output of `print_r($uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']));`

Comment: Result for 
print_r($uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
is:
img/IMG_0640.JPG

Comment: @Rostyslav I tried the same script and it was not working. Finally i changed the permission of that folder `chmod 777 img/` then is has been started working